# Which DFT code allows 'nonuniform grids for Brillouin zone integration'?

Tags: density-functional-theory, software-recommendations, brillouin-zone

In [this Phys. Rev. B article](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.106.155102), Chen, Salzbrenner & Monserrat provide a *[n]onuniform grids for Brillouin zone integration and interpolation*. According to them, they were *able to accelerate the calculation of even complex properties of materials by one to three orders of magnitude* compared to the usual approach based on regular uniform grids.

My question is: is there any DFT code already implementing such a nonuniform grid? In the article, they used VASP and CASTEP, but I couldn't understand if they modified the software's source code to implement this method, or if they somehow implemented it without modifying the source code (and maybe by preparing the input files in some specific way).

Arxiv link of the same article: https://arxiv.org/abs/2208.05981

Answer (score 6):

CASTEP allows you to give it any k-points you like, and I expect other simulations codes do as well. All you need are the k-point coordinates and the integration weights, and the DFT software should handle the rest.

I can imagine it might be tricky to do a tetrahedral integration method for the Brillouin zone integration, but for the common Fourier integration as long as you have the spatial weighting it should just work.

As a side note, these "nonuniform grids" are superpositions of uniform grids, so although CASTEP won't generate the Fairey grid directly, you can just ask it to generate several Monkhorst-Pack sets and then give the union of those points as a k-point list. The only non-trivial part is devising the appropriate weights, but I'm sure there are Voronoi libraries you could use to do that for you.